# .Net 4.5 Issue with IIS - wiping out the .net 4 schema file

Tags: iis-7.5, .net-4.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I've just deployed .net 4.5 on some of our UAT boxes at work (IIS7.5, Windows 2008 R2) and it seems that in one instance it worked fine, but in another it completely ruined the IIS config. More precisely the .Net 4 schema file inside C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\schema was completely blank.

Is this is a known issue and something I should be worried about? I managed to copy the contents of the file from another machine to rectify the issue, but is that good practice and can it return other unforeseen errors?

Cheers,
Jamie

Comment: It appears that .NET setup didn't quite finish or work correctly on this machine. Someone from .NET Setup team is looking into it and will respond soon.

Comment: Let me know if there is anything I can provide log file wise, I might be able to find it on the server. We also doing this on our live boxes today so I'll let you know whether we have any other issues.

Comment: Can you please check the contents of the %windir%\Microsoft.Net\framework64\v4.0.30319\config\ folder and see what is in the IIS schema update files in that folder contain.  Specifically, can you see if any of them are blank?

Comment: I can confirm that none of them are blank. They seem reasonable XML files containing standard asp.net types.

Comment: Can you please collect the setup logs from the affected machine using the tool at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12493 and email them to netfx45compat@microsoft.com

Comment: Apologies for the delay, not had access to the machines. Email has been now been sent.